# Apartir de una ruta hacer un árbol de directorios que muestre todo lo que hay en su interior recursivamente

Tags: java, poo

A partir  de una ruta debería mostrar todo lo que está en su interior, y si tiene directorios estos también deberían mostrar lo que hay dentro, todo esto recursivamente, pero no entiendo porque no sirve :'(.

El método completar busca recorrer toda la ruta de forma recursiva, pero solo se queda en el primer nivel, no entiendo porque pasa esto.

[image: No lee los hijos como nodos]

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;


public class arbol {
    private String ruta;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz;
    
    public arbol() {
        raiz = null;
        ruta = "";
    }
    
    public void setRaiz(String ruta) {
        File directorio = new File(ruta);
        this.raiz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(directorio);
    }
    
     public String getRuta() {
        return ruta;
    }
    
    public DefaultMutableTreeNode getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }
    
    public void completar(String ruta, DefaultMutableTreeNode padre ) {
        File directorio = new File(ruta);
        File aux;
        File[] listado = directorio.listFiles();
        File listadoh[];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode auxiliar;
        if((listado != null)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < listado.length;i++) {
                aux = listado[i];
                auxiliar = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(aux);
                padre.add(auxiliar);
                listadoh = aux.listFiles();
                if(listadoh != null) {
                    for(int j = 0; j< listadoh.length;j++) {
                        completar(listadoh[j].getName(), auxiliar);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void crearArbol(String ruta) {
        completar(ruta, getRaiz());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea anterior era recorrer todos los espaciosos dentro de la ruta y luego ir recorriendo uno por uno para que había dentro recursivamente, pero lo resolví uno a la vez; Dentro una ruta me detengo en su primer elemento, lo registro como nodo, miro si tiene hijos, en caso de que tenga ejecuto el método recursivo y si no paso al siguiente elemento hermano.

También en la pregunta hay un error al pasar completar(listadoh[j].getName(), auxiliar), se está pasando la ruta incompleta, por lo tanto no funcionaría el método.

**Solución**

Reemplazar el método buscar por:

```
public void completar(String ruta, DefaultMutableTreeNode padre ) {
    File directorio = new File(ruta);
    File[] listado = directorio.listFiles();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode aux;
    if(listado != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < listado.length;i++) {
            aux = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(listado[i].getName());
            padre.add(aux);
            if(listado[i].listFiles() != null) {
                completar(ruta+"/"+listado[i].getName(),aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Imagen de la solución**

[image: Solución]

Comment: Hola Camilo, oye y ¿después cómo recorres el árbol para pintarlo como muestras en la imagen de la solución?

Comment: Lo mandas a un Jpanel con el método add